# how to remove home in my site url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

This is my site **https://www.reportsbuyer.com/Home** I want to remove Home in that url using htaccess. I given like this

`RewriteRule ^(Home(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]`

but it will return https://www.reportsbuyer.com/?/Home like this. Please give me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared browser cache?

Comment: yes i cleared everything but it shows like https://www.reportsbuyer.com/?/Home this only.

Comment: I remember similar issue but I think it was mostly up to cache. Clear both server and client side: restart server and test in private browsing window.

Comment: What is home? A Controller?  You can also get rid of the Index.php with htaccess

Comment: Yes its a controller only..

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /homepagepath/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

before index.php mention the name of folder till the base

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /BookCycle/html/index.php/$1 [L,QSA] //Example
```

htdocs/ProjectName/home/{{here start ur application, assets,.htaccess}}
Mention this whole path to solve this problem in the future

Comment: hope it helped.